# Oracle forms compilation error in Unix

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-ebs

We use Oracle ebs R12.2.5 enterprise edition(11i to R12 re-implementation project)

I took the existing forms.fmb file , did the retrofitting changes compiled using forms builder- SUCCESSFULLY compiled.

But when i put the .fmd file in server path and try to compile I get the below message.

can someone help with this, why this error occurring

Error

> Forms 10.1 (Form compiler):Version 10.1.2.3.0
>
> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>
> FRM-10043: Cannot open file

But the file is there in the path. so my question is if we compile a form in forms 11g builder , will that run in 10g version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must modify .fmb file in the same version what the unix server is having. You can open 11g form into 10g form.

By looking your error it seems it is oracle form's 10g Version 10.1.2.3.0 then you should open that fmb file in your local system with the same oracle form's version then edit it and deploye to unix it will be successfully compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Oracle Forms Builder 11g to Create 10g Forms. Create your Forms for 10g using Oracle Forms Builder 10g. There are certain 10g libraries/forms packages that are not applicable to 11g.

Check out [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/stevenChan/entry/latest_forms_and_reports_10g) about Oracle Forms and EBS version compatibility for R12 written by Prasad Akkiraju, Senior Manager in the Applications Technology Integration from Oracle.